# I have a problem in deleting the url of the image received in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making two components and uploading an image from my child component, and show the image in parent component and can delete the image in parent component. But I can't delete the image. Deleting an image is a method of emptying the url of the image by leaving it as "". But even if I press the delete button, the url in the image cannot be erased. I think there is a problem with sending the value of url from child component to parent component as a function. it's deleted well when it's done in one component. I have to divide it into two components right now, so please let me know how to solve it, thanks.

**Cild.jsx:**

this is child component. Upload the image here and pass the url value to parent component through 'toParent'

```js
   import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

   function Child({toParent}) {


//file upload functions
const fileInput = React.useRef(null);

const [isfile,setIsfile] = useState("");

const handleButtonClick = e => {
  fileInput.current.click();
};

const handleChange = e => {
  setIsfile(e.target.files[0]);
  console.log(e.target.files[0]);
}; 

const [preview, setPreview] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
if (isfile) {
  const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(isfile); 
    setPreview(objectUrl);
  }
  return () => URL.revokeObjectURL(isfile);      
}, [isfile]);

//pass state to parent
toParent(preview)

return (
 <h1>
  <input 
    type="file" 
    style={{display:'none'}}
    ref={fileInput}
    onChange={handleChange}
    multiple={true}/>
  <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>
    upload
  </button>
  </h1>
)
}

export default Child;
```

**App.js:**

and this is parent component. Get the url value here and show the image. Also, if I press delete, I want to empty the url of the image, but I can't. How can I empth the url??

```js
   import { useState } from "react";
   import Child from "./Child";

function App() {

//receive state from child
const [isUrl,setIsUrl] = useState("")
const toParent = (url) => {
  setIsUrl(url);
}

//delete image
const handelDelete = (e) => {
  setIsUrl(" ")
}

return (
<div className="App">
  <Child toParent={toParent} />
  <div>
    <img 
    style={{width:'300px', height:'300px'}}
    src={isUrl}/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div onClick={handelDelete}>
      delete
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
   }

  export default App;
```

Comment: what about setting the `display` property to `none`

Comment: It's not in the code here, but the actual code requires an empty url value, so I can't solve it with that. Sorry.

Comment: Put it in a snippet and I'll help.

Comment: I did it. Is this enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```js
setIsUrl("");
```

inside the `handelDelete` method

Comment: I'm sorry. I tried, but it didn't work out

Comment: it did'nt change the src attribute or how?

Comment: I think the original url comes back soon in after it's erased